# Unpivot Data with Multiple Columns - Syntax Help Please

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have the following data in which I would like to unpivot

[image]

I created this query to unpivot the 'Actual' rows but can't seem to figure out the syntax for unpivoting the 'Plan' and 'PriorYear' as well.

```
SELECT FiscalYear, Period, MetricName, ActualValue
FROM vw_ExecSummary
UNPIVOT
(ActualValue FOR MetricName IN ( [Net Revenue], [Total C.S. Salaries]
)) AS unpvt  
WHERE [Type] = 'Actual'
```

The unpivoted data looks like this but I want to also add the Plan and PriorYear columns to the right of the ActualValue column below

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this at the moment, but I think it works like this.  First, you need to `UNPIVOT` *all* the data:

```
SELECT fiscalYear, period, type, metricName, metricValue
FROM vw_ExecSummary
UNPIVOT (metricValue FOR metricName IN ([Net Revenue], [Total C.S. Salaries])) unpvt
```

Which should result in a table that looks something like this:

```
fiscalYear  period  type      metricName             metricValue
===================================================================
15          1       'Actual'  'Net Revenue'          3676798.98999997
15          1       'Actual'  'Total C.S. Salaries'  1463044.72
15          1       'Plan'    'Net Revenue'          3503920.077405
...................... (remaining rows omitted)
```

We could then `PIVOT` the rows as normal to get the new columns (that's what it's for):

```
SELECT fiscalYear, period, metricName, 
       [Actual] AS actualValue, [Plan] AS planValue, [PriorYear] AS priorYearValue
FROM <previous_data>
PIVOT (SUM(metricValue) FOR (type IN ([Actual], [Plan], [PriorYear]) pvt
```

(the `SUM(...)` shouldn't actually do anything here, as presumable the other columns comprise a unique row, but we're required to use an aggregate function)

...which should yield something akin to the following:

```
fiscalYear  period  metricName     actualValue       planValue       priorYearValue
======================================================================================
15          1       'Net Revenue'  3676798.98999997  3503920.077405  40436344.4499999
...................................... (remaining rows omitted)
```

So putting it together would look like this:

```
SELECT fiscalYear, period, metricName, 
       [Actual] AS actualValue, [Plan] AS planValue, [PriorYear] AS priorYearValue
FROM (SELECT fiscalYear, period, type, metricName, metricValue
      FROM vw_ExecSummary
      UNPIVOT (metricValue FOR metricName IN ([Net Revenue], [Total C.S. Salaries])) unpvt) unpvt
PIVOT (SUM(metricValue) FOR type IN ([Actual], [Plan], [PriorYear])) AS pvt
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb5dc/1/0)</kbd>

---

I have just one concern, though:  values like `3676798.98999997`, `3503920.077405`, etc, make me think those columns are *floating point* (ie, `REAL` or `FLOAT`),but the values are named for **monetary uses**.  If this is the case.... you *are* aware floating-point values can't store things like `.1` exactly, right (ie, you can't actually add a dime to a value)?  And that, when values get large enough, you can't add `1` anymore either?  Usually when dealing with monetary values you should be using something based on a fixed-point type, like `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`.

Comment: thanks, for the solution - spot on!   i did notice the parenthesis before the word 'type' in the PIVOT statement is not correct.  i removed it and added a closing parenthesis at the end of the PIVOT statement too.   worked like a charm!

Comment: @Jason - ah, thanks. #corrected#.  This is why I like to test them first.  So what _is_ the type of the two money columns?

Comment: I believe the type is float (not in front of my work laptop at the moment).

Comment: @Jason - ah, well, okay, have fun explaining to accounting where they extra money went/came from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation for [Itzig Ben-Gan's cross apply values pivoting](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/unpivoting-data):

```
create table #data (FiscalYear smallint, Period tinyint, ValueType nvarchar(25), NetRevenue float, Salaries float);
insert into #data values 
    (15,1,N'Actual',3676798.98999,1463044.71999),
    (15,1,N'Plan',3503920.977405,1335397.32878),
    (15,1,N'PriorYear',4043634.449,1543866.89);

select  d.FiscalYear, d.Period,
        ActualNetRevenue = sum(v.ActualNetRevenue), ActualSalaries = sum(v.ActualSalaries),
        PlanNetRevenue = sum(v.PlanNetRevenue), PlanSalaries = sum(v.PlanSalaries),
        PriorYearNetRevenue = sum(v.PriorYearNetRevenue), PriorYearSalaries = sum(v.PriorYearSalaries)
from    #data d
cross apply
        (values
        (N'Actual',d.NetRevenue,d.Salaries,0,0,0,0),
        (N'Plan',0,0,d.NetRevenue,d.Salaries,0,0),
        (N'PriorYear',0,0,0,0,d.NetRevenue,d.Salaries))
        v (ValueType, ActualNetRevenue, ActualSalaries, PlanNetRevenue, PlanSalaries, PriorYearNetRevenue, PriorYearSalaries)
where   d.ValueType = v.ValueType
group by d.FiscalYear, d.Period;

drop table #data;
```

Comment: thanks but this example puts all items in one row.  the above solution is what i was intending to do.